# How to call a protected resource on behalf of a specific user using OAuth2 and JWT token in Spring?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

So we have an authentication server where the UI application gets the access token and then it communicate with API server, it's all good. Now we are building a third application which needs SSO to authenticate the same user and that is fine too.

However, there are scenarios where this third application needs to use some resources on the API server which, from my understanding, we need to get a token from auth server using client-id/secret and then send the request with the access token. This seems ok too, however I am not sure how API server is going to authorise that token (***a hint on this would be great***).

But the main problem is we want this request to be sent on behalf of the user. This is because API server needs to audit all user's activities. **How can we achieve this using Spring Boot/OAuth2 and JWT Token?**

I went through documentation and I know about @EnableOauth2Sso @EnableAuthorisationServer etc. but this scenario is not clear and I'm not even sure it's been implemented in Spring or not.

If there is no implementation for this scenario, what do you recommend? Any experience you have had on this, can you please share?

Comment: There are 4 Grant types/ authentication types in OAuth, where your scenario (authenticating client with user) fits into Grant-type = Password. (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) And you can do that using Spring boot's OAuth with JWT token. HAve a look at this: http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/

Comment: I think you want to say that your 3rd application will communicate with oauth authentication server on behalf of user + client, and if that the case, then sure it can be done easily in Spring OAuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API server plays the role of a Resource Server. There is an annotation designed for that purpose: `@EnableResourceServer`. Your client app then will consume this resource using the handy `OAuth2RestTemplate`.

There are two approaches to properly configure the Resource Server and get this working:

1. Have the public key directly in your resource server app: this way when the client app try to use a token provided by the authorization server to get a resource from the Resource Server, this will verify if the token is valid by itself.
2. Configure the resource server to ask the authorization server if a given access token is valid and depending of the response it will allow or decline to get the resource.

I have posted a [sample app on github](https://github.com/juanzero000/spring-boot-oauth2-jwt) using the first approach. There you can see the interaction between the Authorization Server, the Client and the Resource Server, as well as all the configurations you need for this implementation. Hope it helps you.

Comment: So we want to keep the public key in auth server and it is accessible via endpoint "/oauth/token_key". I've been trying to see if Spring can automatically fetch the public key and use it for token verification but no luck... is there any such feature in spring boot? Anyway, I ended up doing it manually be customising the default token converter JwtAccessTokenConverter

Comment: Try with the `security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-uri` property in your resource server